# Can I block a whole subdomain with one single localhost line?

Tags: dns, domain, localhost, hosts-file, subdomain

I need help with my localhost file, I'm kind of confused & not used to this!

I'd like to block a website, let's say google as a first example.
google has multiple top level domains (.com, .fr, .co.uk, etc...)
If I use `"127.0.0.1 www.google.*"` in my localhost file, will it block all www.google.**x** sites? with **x meaning any top level domains**?

Also, if a website has a subdomain version & a non subdomain version or more subdomains (like imagine [www.donut.com](http://www.donut.com) & donut.com & store.donut.com), should I use `"127.0.0.1 donut.com"` to block all the subdomains of this website?

And last but not least, could I combine the previous commands to block a whole website with all its subdomains & top level domains? Imagine a website (**x**.example.**y** *with **x being multiple subdomains and y being multiple top level domains***), could I block everything using `"127.0.0.1 example.*"` ?

Thanks in advance to everyone willing to help!

Comment: Each domain has to be blocked individually AFAIK

Comment: @JW0914, to be precise each host need to be blocked individually (with `hosts` file). You can't block domains there

Comment: Correct - `hosts` don't allow wildcards AFAIK. There's likely one of several programs that could be installed if using an [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/start) or [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/) compatible router. You can also run a router OS as a _software appliance_ on a normal motherboard, such as BSD-based pFsense or Linux-based Sophos UTM _(UTM comes in two types, a hardware appliance (router hardware with OS), and a software appliance (OS only) which is free for home users)_

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't use `hosts` file on this way. For both Windows and Linux/UNIX operating system expect records like:

```
IP FQDN
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a hosts file - your only other option is to upgrade your router to one with advanced firewall capability.

Cheapest option would be opnsense installed on the correct spec hardware.

https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/hardware.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this for free, using a program perhaps? This would be really helpful in my case...

Comment: @I'mDumbAndCurious, this is another question. Feel free to create one: https://superuser.com/questions/ask

Comment: @I'mDumbAndCurious An OpenWrt or DD-WRT compatible router would likely work - there's multiple software packages that could likely be used

Comment: you need an old Intel dual core pc, a decent network card, dual port broadcoms are decent and cheap, and then a lot of research your end about routers and opnsense. the PC can be really cheap, and the software is free, just go for it. There are no more questions you need to ask... yet!